# Can someone help me optimize the VBA loop in excel

Tags: vba, excel

My worksheet have 6000 rows. This loop takes me more than 20minutes to finish. It is too long for me because I have many columns to run this loop. Can someone help me?

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = ActiveCell.Row To 5771
If Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column - 1).Value = 0 And Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column).Value = "" Then
Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column).Value = 0
ElseIf Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column - 1).Value = 1 Then
Range(Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(i + 9, ActiveCell.Column)).Value = 1
ElseIf Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column - 1).Value = -1 Then
Range(Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(i + 9, ActiveCell.Column)).Value = -1
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Try adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before the loop and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` after the loop.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do. The loop structure you're using appears to be very inefficient: you're looping over *rows* in a range, and performing some evaluation/logic test on each cell.

If the adjacent (to the left) cell's value is 1 or -1, then you're filling the cell *and* the next 9 cells with that value.  But then when you hit the `Next` in your loop, you will perform your test on those cells. So, either you should not be filling a value down 10 rows, or you should avoid testing those rows since presumably nothing needs to be done with them (otherwise you should not have filled them in in the first place!) So you can see why I am a little confused.

In any case, I assume that you *do not need to test the 9 rows beneath* when the `Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column - 1).Value = 1` or `Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column - 1).Value = -1`.

I have not tested either of these so they may have some typos/etc.

The fastest method is to perform manipulations on yoru data in memory only. You can store the range's values in an array, and perform the operations on the array, and then "write" the values back to the worksheet in a single statement. Looping in memory is much faster than looping and writing on the worksheet.

```
Dim rng as Range
Dim arr as Variant
Dim val as Variant
Dim r as Long, i As Integer

Set rng = Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column -1).Address, Cells(5771, ActiveCell.Column).Address)

'store the range values in a variant array:
' this will be of the structure arr(_row#_, _column#_)
arr = rng.Value

For r = 1 to UBound(arr, 1)  'Loop until last row in range/array
    'arr(r,1) represents the first column of the range -- i.e., the column to left of ActiveCell
    ' so we can use a Case statement to check this value of either 0, 1, or -1.
    Select Case arr(r, 1)
        Case 0
            'if the adjacent left cell = 0 AND this cell's value = ""
            ' then make this cell's value = 0. 
            If arr(r, 2) = "" Then arr(r, 2) = 0
        Case 1, -1
            For i = 0 to 10
            'if the value is 1 or -1, puts the in this cell AND the next 9 cells
                arr(r + i, 2) = arr(r, 1)
            Next
            'increment our iterator variable
            r = r + 9
        Case Else
            'Do nothing...
    End Select
Next

'put the transformed values in to the worksheet
rng.Value = arr
```

That is basically the same as this, which uses the worksheet object/cells in the loop. It more closely resembles your loop, but it will also be less efficient than the above.

```
'Alternatively, but this will be slower:
Dim rng as Range
Dim cl as Range
Dim i as Integer

Set rng = Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column -1).Address, Cells(5771, ActiveCell.Column).Address)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For each cl in rng.Cells
    With cl
        Select Case .Offset(0, -1).Value
             Case 0
                 If .Value = "" Then .Value = 0
             Case 1, -1
                 .Resize(10,1).Value = .Offset(0, -1).Value
             Case Else
                 'Do nothing
        End Select
    End With
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Exactly, I don't need to test the 9 rows beneath.  I didn't realize what I did is so inefficient. I just got started using VBA because of the complication of data in my dissertation. Thank you for making my eyes open.

Comment: I just tested your first version of code.  It took me 1 second to finish instead of 20 minutes. It's AMAZING.

Comment: cheers! Which version did you end up using? Also, please do consider marking this answer as "Accepted" so that others with similar problems may benefit from knowing this answer works well :)

Comment: The second version suits me better. I used the first version and found that when there are multiple "1" or "-1" on the left column within 10 rows, only the first "1" or "-1" can be recognize. Instead I intended to let each one to be recognize and fill 10 rows beneath them. Although the first version is quicker, they have little different considering my data is not that huge (5711rows).Thus the second one suites me better. Thank you very much. I already marked your answer because it is perfect.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! I understand what you mean on the first one. It may do what you want if you remove `r = r + 9`. :)